# How does the _mm_cmpgt_epi64 intrinsic work

Tags: x86-64, sse, simd, intrinsics, sse4

I'm using the `_mm_cmpgt_epi64` intrinsic to implement a 128-bit addition, and later a 256-bit one.
Looking at the result of this intrinsic something puzzles me.

I don't understand why the computed mask is the way it is.

```
const __m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi64(bflip, sumflip);
```

And here's the output in my debugger:

```
(lldb) p/x bflip
(__m128i) $1 = (0x00000001, 0x80000000, 0x00000000, 0x80000000)
(lldb) p/x sumflip
(__m128i) $2 = (0x00000000, 0x80000000, 0xffffffff, 0x7fffffff)
(lldb) p/x mask
(__m128i) $3 = (0xffffffff, 0xffffffff, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
```

For the first 64-bit lane (`63:0`) I'm ok. But why the second lane (`127:64`) is not full of ones too?

It seems to me that `0x8000000000000000` > `0x7fffffffffffffff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're printing it in 32-bit chunks, not 64-bit, so that's weird.

But anyway, it's a [**signed** two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) integer compare, as documented in the manual: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPGTQ.html

`0x8000000000000000` is the most negative 64-bit integer, while `0x7fffffffffffffff` is the largest positive.

If you want an unsigned compare, you need to range-shift both inputs by flipping their sign bit.  Logically this is subtracting 2^63 to go from 0..2^64-1 to -2^63 .. 2^63-1.  But we can do it with a more efficient XOR, because XOR is add-without-carry, and the carry/borrow-out goes off the end of the register.

```
const __m128i rangeshift = _mm_set1_epi64x(0x8000000000000000);
const __m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi64(_mm_xor_si128(bflip, rangeshift), _mm_xor_si128(sumflip, rangeshift));
```

Or use AVX512F [`__mmask8 _mm512_cmp[eq|ge|gt|le|lt|neq]_epu64_mask( __m512i a, __m512i b)`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPCMPQ:VPCMPUQ.html)

Comment: Thanks, yes I was a bit confused by the fact that I had already done the xoring (hence the names bflip and sumflip), and so was computing gt op in my head as an unsigned one comparison but of course that was plain wrong.

Comment: What kind of mainstream CPU is supporting this AVX512F?

Comment: @Stringer: no mainstream CPUs yet, just Skylake-server based uarches like i9-78xx (High-end desktop) and Skylake Xeon.  https://www.anandtech.com/show/11550/the-intel-skylakex-review-core-i9-7900x-i7-7820x-and-i7-7800x-tested/3.  And of course Xeon Phi.  Mainstream with CannonLake (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512#CPUs_with_AVX-512).  I think I read some cannonlake laptops may exist in the wild already, but they're not widely available.

Comment: So Intel only, anyway I'm more planning to buy those Zen..., since I already have a Kaby Lake laptop.